# Why do we represent symmetrical interactions between particles as two asymmetrical interactions?

Tags: forces, electrostatics, electric-fields, coulombs-law, interactions

For example, the interaction between two electrons: Both just symmetrically repel each other, but then we go on and describe this as two times the same asymmetric interaction: One particle generating an electric field and the other being moved by that field. Isn't this a very ugly representation? Why do we split up symmetrical interactions into two asymmetrical one?

Edit: I do understand that all electrons contribute to the same field. The question is just why do we differentiate between contributing to the field and being affected by the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re thinking that each particle has its own field, which the other one then feels. That isn't really what happens. What really happens is that the two particles make *one* field and both particles feel that one field. Everything is completely symmetric. All the charges in the universe contribute to *the* electromagnetic field of the universe, and all of them feel it.

When working with finite-size charge distributions, this all works fine. When working with point particles, there are infinities arising from how a particle feels its own field. To avoid these complications, we often pretend that a particle only feels the field of other particles. But that isn't really true.

When a point charge is at rest or in uniform motion, it feels its own field but that field is symmetrical and exerts no net force. When a point charge is  accelerating, the field is asymmetrical and exerts a force on the particle. (It is what makes the particle lose energy as it radiates energy away to infinity!) When a point charge is near a black hole, the field is asymmetrical and there is an electrostatic self-force away from the hole. Yes, an electron tries to push *itself* away from a black hole.

The idea that there is only *one* of each type of field, filling all of spacetime, is a key idea in modern physics. Every electron (and positron, or anti-electron) is a quantum of *one* universal electron field. Every photon is a quantum of *one* universal electromagnetic field.

Comment: That is not my point at all. I understand that in the end, our description of the universe is completely symmetric, it's just that I find this way very ugly - why should we regard contributing to the field and being affected by it as two different things?

Comment: Because cause is not the same as effect.

Comment: Ultimately, the answer to your question is that, as far as we can tell, Nature works this way, and doesn’t care that you find it ugly. Incidentally, every physicist I have ever known considers it extremely beautiful.

Comment: I should also point out that, from the perspective of quantum field theory, this distinction of classical cause and effect more or less goes away. A bunch of quantum fields exist, and they interact. Saying what causes what, and what is affected by what, is somewhat besides the point. They all simply interact with each other. Hopefully you find that more satisfying?

Comment: Yeah, I guess in the context of Quantum Theory it makes a lot more sense, because (I think) it's just that they both exchange e.g. photons with each other. I just thought this was also expressed in classical physics, but seems like we kind of need Quantum Theory to combine cause and effect into one thing.